# Can i get any unique identifier number from apple watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, apple-watch-standalone

I am creating a watch application which is a **standalone app**. I need to generate QR code from any unique ID but I did not get from apple watch. is there any solution for get or generate Unique ID  from apple watch?

Answer (score 0):

To grab the watch device’s uid (vendor specific)

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().identifierForVendor
```

Comment: As i show it is in beta, please look : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice

Comment: That’s okay. Just get the SDK. It won’t be in beta forever ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate UniqueId with current TimeStamp Value, It will be always unique

Comment: But what about when i uninstall and re-install? because we need to login with same unique ID.

Comment: Then how about you display this unique id to your users within the app so that they can store it somewhere. And add a restore data/profile option in which users can enter their previously stored id and restore their app to it's previous state before uninstall.